# How to write JavaScript function in DNN's Open Web Studio control

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have an OWS control for my website's footer.

I have to changes some footer texts dynamically using JavaScript.

Where can I write the JavaScript function in my OWS control?

Answer (score 1):

It probably would be better to put the javascript in a separately loaded file and target the javascript at elements in the footer.  A good place to put the file would be in a javascript directory.  You'll want to modify skin files to load the javascript file.